# MVC-Web API: 405 method not allowed

Tags: c#, html, json, asp.net-web-api2

So, I am stuck in a strange behavior, that is, I am able to send(or POST) data using `Postman (plugin of chrome)` or using `RESTClient(extension of Firefox)`,

[image]

but not able to send it from my html file which lies outside the project. It shows following error when i open the html in chrome:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:1176/api/user/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1176/api/user/. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I am not able to make out why is this happening. Following are the details, you might need to help me solve my error:

**UserController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPIv2.Models;

namespace WebAPIv2.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        static IUserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository();

        [HttpGet]
        public List<TableUser> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return userRepository.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetUser(int id)
        {
            TableUser user = userRepository.Get(id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "User Not found for the Given ID");
            }

            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, user);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(TableUser user)
        {
            user = userRepository.Add(user);
            var response = Request.CreateResponse<TableUser>(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
            string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.UserId });
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
            return response;
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public HttpResponseMessage PutUser(int id, TableUser user)
        {
            user.UserId = id;
            if (!userRepository.Update(user))
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Unable to Update the User for the Given ID");
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteProduct(int id)
        {
            userRepository.Remove(id);
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

**User.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPIv2.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**IUserRepository.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPIv2.Models
{
    interface IUserRepository
    {
        List<TableUser> GetAll();
        TableUser Get(int id);
        TableUser Add(TableUser user);
        void Remove(int id);
        bool Update(TableUser user);
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebAPIv2.Models
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        MastarsFriendsMVCDatabaseEntities userEntities;

        public UserRepository()
        {
            userEntities = new MastarsFriendsMVCDatabaseEntities();
        }

        public List<TableUser> GetAll()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            return userEntities.TableUsers.ToList();
        }

        public TableUser Get(int id)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            var users = userEntities.TableUsers.Where(x => x.UserId == id);
            if (users.Count() > 0)
            {
                return users.Single();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public TableUser Add(TableUser user)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            userEntities.TableUsers.Add(user);
            userEntities.SaveChanges();
            return user;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            TableUser user = Get(id);
            if (user != null)
            {
                userEntities.TableUsers.Remove(user);
                userEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public bool Update(TableUser user)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("student");
            }

            TableUser userInDB = Get(user.UserId);

            if (userInDB == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            userEntities.TableUsers.Remove(userInDB);
            userEntities.SaveChanges();

            userEntities.TableUsers.Add(user);
            userEntities.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPIv2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
//                jQuery.support.cors = true;
//                $.ajax({
//                    url: "http://localhost:1176/api/user/1",
//                    headers: {"Accept": "application/json"},
//                    type: "GET",
//                    success: function(data) {
//                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
//                    },
//                    error: function() {
//                        alert("Error");
//                    }
//                });
//            });

                var user = {
                    UserName: "Disha",
                    Password: "disha123",
                    FirstName: "Disha",
                    LastName: "Vora",
                    Email: "disha@pixielit.com"
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:1176/api/user/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(user),
                    crossDomain: true,
                    headers: {"Accept":"application/json" , "Content-Type":"application/json"},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('User added Successfully');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('User not Added');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers:" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method:" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <!--<add name="Allow" value="*"/>-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MastarsFriendsMVCDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-WWU3DMLR6PX\PIXIELIT;initial catalog=MastarsFriendsMVCDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=sa_12345;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162825/web-api-put-request-generates-an-http-405-method-not-allowed-error

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Sir, I am already applying the solution in my project. But, no success... :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WebApi probably blocks the CORS request. To enable CORS on WebApi, use the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package. For further details, check http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 25):

Ok. Solved the problem with the help of @martennis answer, but with a little correction.

Every things perfect, just to take care is, we need to enter following command in Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors –IncludePrerelease
```

Instead of the one shown in the link provided by, @martennis, and after that, my **WebApiConfig.cs** was updated as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace WebApiRESTfulwithJSON
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Hence, solved the problem...!!!

Now, I will able to use my web services from anywhere, calling it from mobile applications, web applications or desktop applications.

For, how to create them from scratch, I wrote my first blog on this (...inspite of being android developer, never tried to write a blog for Android :-P Anyways...)

Link: http://programmingwithease.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/learning-asp-net-web-api-2-using-c/

Comment: Solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

No need webconfig, all you need is to add:

```
  services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing "using System.Web.MVC" from controller class solved this problem for me.