# custom and regular methods in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

at first I had ordinary GET/POST/PUT/DELETE requests to my server, and this config.route of my web api was enough:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

then, I needed a custom action (for example, instead of api/User/212 - GET, I want to api/GetAllUsers  - GET)

so I changed the config to that:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get" ,id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiGet",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiPost",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "post", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiPut",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "put", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiDelete",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "delete", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

the problem now, is that I can't reach the classic GET ('DefaultApiGet).

**EDIT**

In another words, if I have a user that I want to get his one post, or all posts then I want to be able to do that (user id = 12345):
'api/UserPost/12345' - get last post of user 12345
and
'api/UserPost/GetAll/12345' - get all posts of user 12345

Comment: Can you try removing `id = RouteParameter.Optional` in your "DefaultApiWithAction" route?

Comment: I tried, but now the POST is not working. I get: 405 - method not allowed

Comment: Is this of any help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293782/mvc-web-api-405-method-not-allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and the solution are well explained [here](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/)