# POST Request with Jquery's $.post(), 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, post, .net-4.6

I have an asynchronous task set up in a C# controller like so that has been simplified here:

namespace MyApp.Api
{

```
public class TimeAllocationController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("api/timeallocation")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActivityValidationResult> Post(string id)
    {
        //logic here...
    }
```

Ideally I'd like to pass the whole payload in JQuery using the $.post() method, but I keep getting a `405 method not allowed` if

I try to pass in C#'s `Post()` string Id within the payload. I can only pass it in like so:

```
$.post('/api/timeallocation/' + categoryId...
```

I cannot pass it in like so:

```
$.post('/api/timeallocation?id=' + categoryId...
```

I'd like to do neither of the above, just set up a `payload` variable in the JS file with the id and all the other required attributes, and call `$.post()` on that.

As for other possible reasons for the 405 error, I have verified that it is not due to authentication reasons.

Is there something I am overlooking here?

Comment: You need to change the route configuration to `[Route("api/timeallocation/{id}")]` and do `$.post('/api/timeallocation/' + categoryId` to call from Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the following in my controller:

```
public async Task<ActivityValidationResult> Post(string id, [FromBody] TimeAllocationActivity payload)
```

where `payload` handles the `TimeAllocationActivity` attributes. Note I did have to create the `TimeAllocationActivity` model as it did not exist before.

On the JS side I created the payload variable and then set up the request like so:

```
processCheckAjax = $.ajax({
    url: "/api/timeallocation/" + categoryId,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(payload)
```

I do find it odd that I still had to append `categoryId` to the route and it could not be included in the payload.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call it with a payload from jquery you should have your Post method with the `[FromBody]` attribute like this:

```
public class TimeAllocationController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("api/timeallocation")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActivityValidationResult> Post([FromBody] string id)
    {
        //logic here...
    }
```

[See the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

And then you can call it with

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/timeallocation/",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: categoryId
    }
});
```

Comment: I was unware of `[FromBody]`. Whether it be your answer or others posted here, it seems the only way I can NOT get a 405method error is if I do `Post(string id`) in the controller and in the JS have the route be `$.post('api/timeallocation/' + categoryId...` . Any use of `FromUri`, `FromBody`, query string (ie, `?id=categoryId`) always returns a 405. What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Can you share the complete code of how you are doing the post? You mentioned in your question that you're passing multiple attributes so maybe this answer is of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518529/95499. Basically doing `data: JSON.stringify(payload),`

Comment: Other thing to consider, but I don't know since it's not in the code snippet you provided; have you enabled CORS? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26649361/95499

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
$.post('/api/timeallocation/', categoryId)
```

Or you can add [FromUri] attribute of id parameter and call

```
$.post('/api/timeallocation?id' + categoryId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TimeAllocationController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("api/timeallocation")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActivityValidationResult> Post(JObject json)
    {
        string id = json["id"];
        //login here
    }
}

or

public class TimeAllocationController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("api/timeallocation")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActivityValidationResult> Post(dynamic json)
    {
        string id = json.id ?? "";
        //login here
    }
}

$.ajax({
    url: "/api/timeallocation/",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: categoryId
    }
});
```